# Python xpath problems

Tags: python, html, xpath

[html-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiX1X.png)

In the end i want to get the data stored in the div element with class="large-12 columns tag-bar tag-text" which is cat in the example.

When using xpath with python:

```
print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]'))
print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]/div[1]'))
print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]/div[1]/div[4]'))
```

the first one returns the "main" div element as expected, however the second and third one return an empty list. 
Is there any particular reason for this behaviour?

Comment: can you share which url you are trying to scrapy?

Comment: https://imagga.com/auto-tagging-demo?url=https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg

Comment: Check my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your tree is not the one show in the picture, suppose the tree is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
tree = '<div id="tags-holder">\
    <div class="tags-holder1">\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar concept"></div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns rel-bar">test</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns percentage">100.00%</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar tag-text">cat</div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="tags-holder2">\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar concept"></div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns rel-bar">test</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns percentage">100.00%</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar tag-text">dog</div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="tags-holder3">\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar concept"></div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns rel-bar">test</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns percentage">100.00%</div>\
        <div class="large-12 columns tag-bar tag-text">elphant</div>\
    </div>\
</div>'
print Selector(text=tree).xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]')
print Selector(text=tree).xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]/div[1]')
print Selector(text=tree).xpath('//*[@id="tags-holder"]/div[1]/div[4]/text()').extract()
```

The output will be:

```
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="tags-holder"]' data=u'<div id="tags-holder">    <div class="ta'>]
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="tags-holder"]/div[1]' data=u'<div class="tags-holder1">        <div c'>]
[u'cat']
```

Your logic is correct for this case, just need to use `text()` and `extract()`

**Update:**

Based on your provided url, I found that the `<div id="tags-holder">` is generated by the javascript, but Scrapy downloads the whole response before running your callback, it means that the javascript generated content will not be in the response. If you view the source code, `tags-holder` is empty:

```
<h6 id="concepts">Concepts</h6>

<div id="tags-holder" class="holder" style="display: block;">
</div>

<div id="tags-holder-extra" class="holder">
</div>
```

That's why your first `xpath` has return, but other two return empty.

if you use the browser developer tools (Firefox, Google Chrome or Safari), in Chrome you can open it Menu->Tools->Developer Tools, then from here you can see the whole loaded response.

I think you better try with `selenium` and `splash` will work for this kind of dynamic website.